# Centering Command Works Fine Outside the TOC; but Inside is a Different Story

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, errors, compilation-error, center

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A LONG SENTENCE THAT WILL NOT FIT ON ONE LINE, AND SO IT WILL BE DISPLAYED ON MORE THAN ONE LINE, ALL OF WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER.\par}

%\tableofcontents
%\addtocontents{toc}{{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A LONG SENTENCE THAT WILL NOT FIT ON ONE LINE, AND SO IT WILL BE DISPLAYED ON MORE THAN ONE LINE, ALL OF WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER.\par}} 
\end{document}]
```

which produces the output

[image]

No problem!

However, when I take the same centering code and insert it into an `addtocontents` command, running the following

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A LONG SENTENCE THAT WILL NOT FIT ON ONE LINE, AND SO IT WILL BE DISPLAYED ON MORE THAN ONE LINE, ALL OF WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER.\par}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{{\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A LONG SENTENCE THAT WILL NOT FIT ON ONE LINE, AND SO IT WILL BE DISPLAYED ON MORE THAN ONE LINE, ALL OF WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER.\par}} 
\end{document}]
```

I get the following error display:

[image]

QUESTION: What is causing the problem here, and how may I correct it so that I may easily add and center text that extends onto more than one line in the TOC?

Thank you.

Comment: ToC has own definition for items styles. They are mostly (always) left aligned ...

Comment: Check what is written into the toc file.

Comment: You probably have an old latex where some of the commands are still fragile, protect the commands with e.g. `\protect\centering`.

Comment: The posted document runs without error on any recent latex release

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the `\protect\centering` suggestion.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps you will consider posting your comment as an answer for those like myself who for various reasons, do not have up-to-date versions of Latex. Your suggestion works perfectly inserted as follows: `\addtocontents{toc}{{\protect\centering\Large\bfseries HERE IS A LONG SENTENCE THAT WILL NOT FIT ON ONE LINE, AND SO IT WILL BE DISPLAYED ON MORE THAN ONE LINE, ALL OF WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER.\par}} `  and produces output in the TOC exactly as I had hoped. Thank you again for your most efficient and helpful suggestion.

Comment: You are using an outdated latex. And answer is imho not really useful for other users. apart from this there are various answers about protect already on the site.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. thank you.